# How can I alter procedure based on the information present in an excel file using SSIS and SQL

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis

I receive an excel file with following info:
Source_column_name,Source_table_name,Destination_column,Destination_table,Where_clause_Condition,Join_condition,Procedure_name,Created_date,Modified_date

> [ColumnS1],   [TableS1],  [ColumnD1], [TableD1],  [Where
>   TableS1.Condition1 = ‘XYZ’]   ,[INNER JOIN TableS0 ON TableS1.X1=
>   TableS0.X2],  [Proc_XYZ], [today's date]
>   [ColumnS2],   [TableS2],  [ColumnD2], [TableD2],  [Where
>   TableS2.Condition2 = ‘XYZ’],  [INNER JOIN TableS0 ON TableS2.X1=
>   TableS0.X2],  [Proc_ABC], [Old date], [Today’s date]

If created date is today's date then source column should be added to table and also proc should be altered ie add column is select statement in proc and  add table name along with join and where clause condition.
If modified date is today's date then only proc needs to be altered with where clause condition wherever the table is used (TableS2 is the above case).

Can anyone please help with any approach.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the answer, but the question is frightening. Avoiding SQL injection risks looks unlikely with the pieces/parts you're trying to fuse.

Comment: Yes I was also thought about dynamic SQL. However,appending a join condition while altering proc is a hard part I see

Comment: Whitelisting the table and column names by checking against the [Information Schema Views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) may be the easiest part. Applying [`QuoteName`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to the object names won't be easy. You'll need to assign a new table alias for each joined table to ensure that other references to the table don't conflict. Then fix up the references to use the alias. ...

Comment: What is the proc you are thinking of altering and why?   This is probably an XY problem.

Comment: Proc is basically selecting data from multiple tables and inserting into a single destination table.

Comment: There is no staging or temp table  used in proc

Answer (score 0):

Don't alter the proc dynamically.

Instead put conditional logic in the proc, and pass parameters to it that tell it what to do based on the incoming data.

Since you haven't shared any code, sample data or desired results, I can't be any more specific than that, unfortunately.